# Save timestamp to firesote using cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How do I save a timestamp value to firestore using cloud functions.

I tried this (adding 30 days to the timestamp) but it ends up saving the value as a number

```
var now = new Date();

   await docRef.update({
       'subscription':{
          package:req.query.package,
          endDate: now.setTime(now.getTime()+(30 *24+60+60+1000))
        }
     })
```

[image: firestore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add days to the date, then you should `setDate()` instead. By using `setTime()` you're setting the time instead of the date. See code below:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);

   await docRef.update({
       'subscription':{
          package: req.query.package,
          endDate: now
        }
     })
```

---

For more information, you should check out this documentations:

- [Date.prototype.setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)
- [Date.prototype.getDate()](https://Date.prototype.getDate())